# Invalid mime type "application/xmlcharset=UTF-8": Invalid token character '=' in token "xmlcharset=UTF-8"

Tags: spring-webflux

I am using a 3rd party service which returns 201 for one of the service with the contentType

> "application/xmlcharset=UTF-8"

Here, there is no semicolon b/w xl and charset and causing error. The service gets invoked successful, but error while consuming the response.

```
private void acknowledge(Depts depts){
    return webClient.post().uri(BASE_URL)
                    .bodyValue(depts).retrieve()
                    .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, ServiceExceptionHandler::handleServiceError)
                    .bodyToMono(ClientResponse.class);
}
```

**Error :-**

```
 reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "application/xmlcharset=UTF-8": Invalid token character '=' in token "xmlcharset=UTF-8"
Caused by: org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "application/xmlcharset=UTF-8": Invalid token character '=' in token "xmlcharset=UTF-8"
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:620) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:967) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.http.ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.getContentType(ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.java:60) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readWithMessageReaders(BodyExtractors.java:189) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$toMono$2(BodyExtractors.java:85) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.body(DefaultClientResponse.java:132) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.bodyToMono(DefaultClientResponse.java:147) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$bodyToMono$2(DefaultWebClient.java:541) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceExchangeFilterFunction$TraceWebClientSubscriber.onNext(TraceExchangeFilterFunction.java:178) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceExchangeFilterFunction$TraceWebClientSubscriber.onNext(TraceExchangeFilterFunction.java:141) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:387) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:654) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at reactor.netty.resources.NewConnectionProvider$NewConnectionObserver.onStateChange(NewConnectionProvider.java:190) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:629) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1534) ~[netty-handler-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1283) ~[netty-handler-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1330) ~[netty-handler-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:508) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:447) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.60.Final.jar:4.1.60.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "application/xmlcharset=UTF-8": Invalid token character '=' in token "xmlcharset=UTF-8"
    at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeTypeInternal(MimeTypeUtils.java:261) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentLruCache.get(ConcurrentLruCache.java:107) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:617) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

**Invoking code**

```
return Mono.when(monoPubs).then(service.acknowledge(depts))
                .thenReturn(deptId);
```

Here, the response is 201 and I am good to ignore this error. Not sure, How to ignore this error  in the reactive call?

Comment: Did you try to use `.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` before the `.bodyValue(depts)`?

Comment: It’s working if there is ; b/w xml and charset.